# How to find sum of this series? $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{3k-2}{5k}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to find sum of this series?

$$\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1\cdot 4}{5\cdot 10}+\frac{1\cdot 4\cdot 7}{5\cdot 10\cdot 15}-\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{3k-2}{5k}$$

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Does $1.4.7$ mean $1\times4\times7$?

Comment: yes @PeterWoolfitt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf HINT:$ Maybe the expansion of binomial series will help:- $$(1+x)^{\nu}=1+\binom {\nu}1x+\binom {\nu}2x^2+\binom {\nu}3x^3+...$$ Use the first 3 terms to determine $x$ and $\nu$.

Comment: @learningmaths: This is a very good hint and I would be wondering what business you have working on this problem if you did not have the ability to take it from here.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
{1 \over 5} - {1\cdot 4 \over 5\cdot 10}
+{1\cdot 4\cdot 7 \over 5\cdot 10\cdot 15} - \cdots}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}{3k - 2 \over 5k}
\\[5mm]&=-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 5}}^{n}{1 \over n!}
\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}\pars{3k - 2}
={1 \over 5}
-\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 5}}^{n}{1 \over n!}
\dsc{\prod_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}\pars{3k - 2}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}&\ln\pars{\dsc{\prod_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}\bracks{3k - 2}}}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}\ln\pars{3k - 2}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}{3k - 3 \over t + 3k - 3}\,{\dd t \over t}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}
\bracks{1 - {t \over 3k + t - 3}}\,{\dd t \over t}
=\int_{1/3}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{n - 1 \over t} - \sum_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}{1 \over k + t - 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{1/3}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{n - 1 \over t} - \Psi\pars{t + n} + \Psi\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{\Lambda\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{n - 1}\ln\pars{3\Lambda}
-\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\Lambda + n} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3 + n}}
+\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\Lambda + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{4/3}}}
\\[5mm]&=\ln\pars{3^{n - 1}\,{\Gamma\pars{n + 1/3} \over \Gamma\pars{4/3}}}
\\[5mm]&\imp\quad
\dsc{\prod_{k\ =\ 2}^{n}\bracks{3k - 2}}
=\dsc{3^{n - 1}\,{\pars{n - 2/3}! \over \pars{1/3}!}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
{1 \over 5} - {1\cdot 4 \over 5\cdot 10}
+{1\cdot 4\cdot 7 \over 5\cdot 10\cdot 15} - \cdots}
={1 \over 5} - \sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 5}}^{n}\,{1 \over n!}\,
3^{n - 1}\,{\pars{n - 2/3}! \over \pars{1/3}!}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 5} - {1 \over 3}\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\,
\pars{-\,{3 \over 5}}^{n}{\pars{n - 2/3}! \over \pars{n - 1}!\pars{1/3}!}
={1 \over 5} - {1 \over 3}\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\,
\pars{-\,{3 \over 5}}^{n}{n - 2/3 \choose n - 1}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 5} - {1 \over 3}\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\,
\pars{-\,{3 \over 5}}^{n}{-4/3 \choose n - 1}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}
={1 \over 5} + {1 \over 3}\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}
{-4/3 \choose n - 1}\int_{0}^{3/5}t^{n - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 5} + {1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{3/5}
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{-4/3 \choose n}t^{n}\,\dd t
={1 \over 5} + {1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{3/5}\bracks{\pars{1 + t}^{-4/3} - 1}\,\dd t
=\color{#66f}{\Large 1 - {5^{1/3} \over 2}}
\\[5mm]&\approx{\tt 0.1450}
\end{align}

Comment: well done man@felix

Comment: @learningmaths Thanks. It was a little painful.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the series is: $$1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{5}.$$
As suggested by Abhishek Bakshi, this comes from considering the Taylor series of
$$ f(x) = \left(1+\frac{3}{5}x\right)^{1/3} $$
around $x=0$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-\frac{1}{3}$ in the exponent?